# Get 403 response with the "new" Firebase Cloud Messaging API

Tags: android, firebase, google-oauth, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are successfully using the [Legacy HTTP Server Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) on our server for FCM.
I wanted to update to [FCM HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) today.

I did it [step by step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) and when the server calls the request, we get this response:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[projectid]/messages:send
```

This is the server code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[projectid]/messages:send");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(req.getBytes("UTF-8"));

// Exception happen here
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

The getAccessToken():

```
private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(ClientApiServlet.context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/[projectid].json")))         .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));
        googleCredential.refreshToken();
        return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
}
```

I have downloaded the json file from the adminsdk page of the firebase cloud.

All with the same projectid...

I updated these 2 libs on the server:

```
google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar
google-oauth-client-1.23.0.jar
```

The getAccessToken() methode returned an accesstoken: "ya29.c.Elr0BAa..."

I think, I miss a small step, maybe you could help?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
It is working now with the hint of **arterpa**! Thanks again!

After that I got a 400 error, so something in the request data was wrong:

The problem was, we didn't converted all `data{...}`values to strings. With the legacy protocol it was not an issue, but with FCM HTTP v1 API it has to be strings! ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had this problem, and it seems you need to enable FCM API for your project at [Google API console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard).

Comment: I am saying that I previously ran into this problem, but fixed it. I got a 403 forbidden because to use the new FCM HTTP v1 API, you need to enable FCM API on your Google API dashboard first, which was previously not needed for the legacy HTTP protocol.

Comment: Explanation is reasonable. Be aware that short answers are automatically flagged for review and it didn't look at first glance at least, sufficient. Your comment is noted though and flag removed.

Comment: Thank you!!  FCM API was automatically enabled but FCM Messaging API had not been.  https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/fcm.googleapis.com/

Comment: There's no option of FCM API in the dashboard now, only Google Cloud Messaging. Which is already enabled. Been stuck in this mess for ages now

`API solution not found with service name: fcm.googleapis.com`

Comment: Hi all, how long do I have to wait from the time I click enable on the FCM Messaging API in the Google API Dashboard to it being efficient? I clicked on it about 10 minutes ago and it is now enabled but I'm still receiving the HTTP 403 Forbidden error. I have restarted my app server already.

Comment: From the dashboard click "ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES" -> search for FCM -> select "Firebase Cloud Messaging API" -> Enable

Comment: for me the emails for fcm dashboard , and google api services are not same .. what should i do

Comment: For me all services were already enabled. I also tried to generate new keys... No progress so far...

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue of getting a 403 from the FCM HTTP v1 API. I had FCM Messaging API enabled, but my problem was that the service account I was using didn't have the correct role to make requests to the FCM API. You can try creating a new service account with the "project Owner" role to see if that helps.