# How to get permissions / scope for Google Apps Script to Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP v1 API?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a Firebase Cloud Message from Google Apps Script. I have followed the following questions & links & assembled the following code:

[Get 403 response with the "new" Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019009/get-403-response-with-the-new-firebase-cloud-messaging-api)

The `res`|`error` I am receiving is:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

My Code in Google Apps Script is:

```
function sendFCM(text){
  text = {
    "message": {
      "topic": "news",
      "notification": {
        "title": "Breaking News",
        "body": "New news story available."
      },
      "data": {
        "story_id": "story_12345"
      }
    }
  }
  var projectId = "xxxxxxx";
  var apiUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"+projectId+"/messages:send";
  var authKey = "AAAU.......Cs";
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(text),
    headers:{Authorization: "Bearer "+ token},
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

Script's properties > User Scopes list follwoing:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

FCM & GCM Api is enabled in project's developer console.

Edit:

From [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898341/how-to-get-permissions-scope-for-google-apps-script-to-firebase-cloud-messagin#comment96564985_54898341)'s comment, I added the following scope to app manifest:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging
```

Upon Run, it asked me to authorize & now the `response` is an instance of a Message. But still I do not know how to define a `to` device i.e. to which device the message should go.

```
{
  "name": "projects/send-xxxx3/messages/866xxxxx92"
}
```

Comment: When the API has already been enabled, although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about including ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging`` in the scopes? [Ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server?hl=en)

Comment: Ok, I added the above scope in manifest json file in Apps Script, & now it just gives the output object `name:projects/send-notifxxxxxxxa3/messages/5550xxxxx087" I will look now how to target the specific device? & What does this response means. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, by adding the scope, it was found that your script worked. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And you can see the detail information at [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message?hl=en#send_messages_to_specific_devices).